# Acrobat - Possible to create custom link to text box/section?

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I'm using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC to finish a manual I am building.

I'm trying to link certain areas of the manual to other areas (i.e. create an active hyperlink that takes to user to a different section of the manual).

I do NOT want to simply link to a page # because I anticipate that the manual will be growing over the next few years and I don't want to have to reset all of my page links every time I come out with a new update.

So, is there a way to link to a specific text box, or other item, so that when new pages get added the hyperlink will always direct the user to the same place?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this manually (which I kind of assume), you are using the Link tool, and when you are asked to navigate to the place where the link should get you, you set the according view (place on page and zoom factor). Then also adjust the settings for the link (zoom factor, for example).

The link will remember this, and you will get the correct view.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, doesn't the workflow you describe link to a [page number]?  What happens if on my original document the [page number] = 10, but at a later date I insert an additional page at the beginning?. I would now want the link to go to page 11, but don't want to update each link manually when the page numbers change. I'm trying to find a way to link to a specific Item to avoid the issue.  In other words, if I link to an item on page 10 - and then insert an additional page. The item would move to page 11, but the link would still go to the right place.. Does that make sense?

Comment: The workflow I described links to a View (which is on a particular page, agreed). In order to handle changing number of pages, you would link to  Named Destinations.